# object has no attribute 'exists'

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.3 and trying to use .exists() on a model entry but get the error listed below.  Exists() was included in Django 1.2 so I should have access to it.  I verified my version using django.get_version and it was okay.
Querying MyModel based on pk only returns an entry but querying with .exists() throws an error.  Do I need to imports something?

```
>>> m = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> m
<MyModel: Model field entry 1>
>>> m = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1).exists()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

Comment: Or try `MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).exists()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`exists()` [is a method of a `QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists).

`get()` returns a single model instance, and [will raise an exception `Entry.DoesNotExist` if that instance doesn't exist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get). So you'll need to wrap this in a `try/except` block if you're not sure if an instance with that `id` exists.

Answer (score 1):

try use .filter() instead .get(), like this:

```
m = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).exists()
y = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=2).exists()
print(m)
print(y)
```

output must to be a bool, exemple:

```
False
True
```

suposing that m does not exist and y exists

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Django 1.7 on my project and my codes like :

```
try:
    temp_query_set = YourModelName.functionName()
except ObjectDoesNotExists:
    <do something>
```

note that, my code (at first) using  `if query_set.exists()`
it works fine when there is no query set returned, but raise error `object does not have attribute 'exists'` when there is something returned.
so pls try avoid using `if <something>.exists()` 
CMIIW